# Drop down menu not work on opera

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I am using the [scrollToFix](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) script on my website to fix the Navigation as the user scrolls down the page.

The drop down menu runs correctly on all Browsers except Opera. When i scroll down the page, the hover menu do not work on Opera Browser

Print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qODqh.jpg

Demo live link: http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/263/

*Note: I'm using External Resources on jsfiddle.net

I using this code for ScrollToFix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#navigasi_menu').scrollToFixed(); 
    });
</script>
```

For css code and html code, please view the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/263/

Please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the background to the "a" tag instead of the list, like so:

```
#navigasi_menu li:hover {
float:left;
list-style:none;
}

#navigasi_menu li:hover a { background: #999; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/264/)